# Google Picker ViewId for mp3 files

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

I am trying to get the Google Picker to let the user select only mp3 files. I have looked at the documentation for Picker but didn't see any info what the ViewID should be for Mp3 files. Also, trying to show all the files with `addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).` isn't working. Does someone know how to load just .mp3's or all the files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 'load just the mp3 files' as far as I've tested but there's 'load all files which includes mp3s'.

Just follow the [Picker API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) code and change these parts:

FROM

```
var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'
```

TO

```
var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
```

(in createPicker().. ) FROM

```
addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS).
```

TO

```
addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
```

and then when the picker selector appears, you can type .mp3 and in the search box and it'll show all the mp3 files.

See screenshot below:
[image]